# How to specify bookmark and TOC title separately

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks

I customize a dash symbol

```
\newcommand{\shortdash}{\rule[.7ex]{0.5em}{0.5pt}}
```

to minimize the space around when typesetting in non-english situation. When I used it in `\section`, it works in text and TOC(table of content), but it leaves the arguments `[.7ex]{0.5em}{0.5pt}` in bookmark.

I try to specify an alternative title like `\section[alternative]{real title}`, but the TOC also changes.

What I want is to specify a title for text and TOC, but another title for bookmark alone. How to realize that? Or how to reduce the failure title-handling of `hyperref`?

Comment: lease help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry, I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\texorpdfstring` will decide which feature is to be used either in normal 'text' (like in the TOC) and a text with pdf features such as the bookmarks.

The command `\rule` is fragile, so it should be used in conjunction with a `\protect`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcommand{\shortdash}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\rule[.7ex]{0.5em}{0.5pt}}{--}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First\shortdash of two}
\section{Second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Owesome! I just get the idea of `\texorpdfstring`, but have not  yet considered this definition.